# Where can I find WebAssembly's binary instructions table

Tags: binary, virtual-machine, webassembly

I am making a webassembly compiler, and I need to know WebAssembly's binary instructions to generate the wasm file. The problem is that there seems to be no source of the opcodes. I can only find just some short examples, but I need the full instructions table. I also need to know how code blocks, functions and other statements are expressed (**in raw binary format**)

Comment: Thanks @ColinE for the help. I have seen the official doc but not very in depth. I downloaded the pdf version and I thought it was the same as the online doc, and when I didn't saw any instruction table, I thought that the online doc didn't have it too (pdf cuz I'm offline for most of the time). I have seen chasm and the blog post about it and even your speech. Thats what inspired me for the compiler. I would be very happy if you could help me with it as someone with a lot more experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary source for this information is the WebAssembly specification which has a specific section that covers the binary format:

https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/binary/index.html

There is also a non-official guide which is a little more compact and readable:

https://github.com/sunfishcode/wasm-reference-manual